# Bind button with jQuery on MediaWiki

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediawiki

I have a `button` and `div` on my MediaWiki page:
In `Mediawiki:Common.js` I have function:

```js
;(function($) {    
    $(function() {
        $('#b_add').on('click', function(e) {
            $("#msgid").html("This is Hello World by JQuery");
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<button id="b_add">Add</button>
<div id="msgid"></div>
</html>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I understand that jQuery is enabled by default in MediaWiki (I use v1.27). Is there anything else I should configure to have it running? Or did I make some mistake in the code? (I have just started using JS)

Comment: Check the updated snippet

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console window in the actual page? And can you tell if you script is actually loaded and executed?

Comment: @pedram jQuery is auto loaded in MediaWiki. When I put `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` outside of the <html> tags it is displayed as text.

Comment: No need to put `jquery` twice.. I mean this works here in this snippet.

Comment: @GolezTrol I added `if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is loaded => print the version
    alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
}` to `mediawiki:common.js` and pop-up window is displayed when I'm loading my page. It displays 1.11.3 version of jQuery.

Comment: @pedram ahh ok, so it must be something related to MediaWiki. Thanks.